# how can i get auto height on li tag to responsive menu

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

i have a a problem with css, i have a ul with 100% height and 6xli on it, i want to fix li to cover the screen all 100% width (100/6)% height to make this responsive..

```css
.reset {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.iphone_screen {
  width: 375px;
  height: 627px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.iphone_screen>ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.iphone_screen>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%; /* (100/6) */
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="iphone_screen reset">
  <ul class="reset">
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead  `height: calc(100% / 6);`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pre17op/

```
.iphone_screen>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 6);
  /* (100/6) */
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.reset {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.iphone_screen {
  width: 375px;
  height: 627px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.iphone_screen>ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.iphone_screen>ul>li {
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="iphone_screen reset">
  <ul class="reset">
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
    <li>li menu</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```